# Azure Cloud Service web role + worker example on PHP

Tags: php, azure

I need an example of web role and worker written on PHP which demonstrates
communication between role and worker on Microsoft Azure Cloud Service.
The demonstration of putting message to queue, processing it with worker and sending response back to web role.
I found example on C# only.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-create-web-role/. HTH

Answer (score 0):

http://azure.microsoft.com/uk-ua/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-queues/

Actually, is not possible to send response back to the web role which added a message to queue from worker.
Thanks everyone for help, the question is solved.